# question related to the norm of bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $T\in\mathcal{L}(E)$, we have
$$
\|T\|=\sup\left\{|\langle Tx\mid y\rangle|;\;x,y\in E,\;\|x\|\leq1,\|y\|\leq1\right\}.
$$

> How we can deduce that
>   $$
> \|T\|=\sup\left\{|\langle Tx\mid y\rangle|;\;x,y\in E,\;\|x\|= 1,\|y\|=1\right\}?
> $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x,y$ such that $0<\|x\|,\|y\|<1$, then 
\begin{align*}
\left|\left<T\left(\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}\right),\left(\dfrac{y}{\|y\|}\right)\right>\right|\leq M:=\sup\{\left|\left<Tx,y\right>\right|:x,y\in E,\|x\|=1,\|y\|=1\}
\end{align*}
by definition, so 
\begin{align*}
|\left<Tx,y\right>|\leq M\cdot\|x\|\cdot\|y\|<M,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\sup\{\left|\left<Tx,y\right>\right|:x,y\in E,\|x\|\leq 1, \|y\|\leq 1\}\leq M.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think that the proof works if we take $x,y$ such that $0<\|x\|,\|y\|\leq 1$  .I think we don't need that $\|x\|,\|y\|<1$

Comment: Yes, yes, $\leq$ should be the right one corresponding to your question, so my answer actually suggests the fact that it is equivalent to the $<$ version.

Answer (score 2):

For any $x$ with $\|x\|<1$, let $c=1/\|x\|>1$. Then you have 
$$
|\langle Tx,y\rangle\leq |\langle T(cx),y\rangle|,
$$
and $\|cx\|=1$. Similarly with $y$.